# How to select text in a cell of a table in MSWOrd using delphi automation?

Tags: delphi, ms-word, text-alignment

I have difficulties understanding the Selection in Word Automation.
To make it short, I want to have a table somewhere in my generated Word document, and I need to make alignments to the text inside a particular cell. How do I achieve that?

I use the ComObj approach:

```
  var
   MsWord: Variant;
  ...
  try
    MsWord := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    try
      MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      MsWord.Visible := True;
    except
      Exception.Create('Error');
    end;
  end;
```

How do I tell Word where is the text (cell) to be able later to align it?
I use this code to add text to a cell:

```
Function AddTextToTableCell(Table:integer;Row, Column:integer;text:string):boolean;
begin
  AddTextToTableCell:=true;
  try
    MsWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(Table).Columns.Item(Column).Cells.Item(Row).Range.Text:=text;
  except
    AddTextToTableCell:=false;
  end;
End;
```

Can I somehow modify this to set the alignment of the text inside the cell? Let's say I want to center-align the cell located at: row:1 and column:3. My cell has multiple (variable) lines of text. I want to center it horizontally and vertically.

I searched other code of automation on Google and this line should do the trick, except it does not in delphi...(seems like VB equivalent works with it):

```
MSWORD.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(Table).Cell(Row,Column).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```

If I use

```
MSWORD.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(Table).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

then all the cells in the table are aligned to horiz-center. I only want one particular cell and I want it to be centered vertically too

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: You could record a macro and take the adapted code for delphi.

Comment: Well I tried that, but still, there is no way of knowing how many rows are in my cell in order to select them all. Plus, I would need to know exactly how many characters I need to pass since entering the table, until i reach my desired CELL. That is not applicable

Comment: Also if I am located inside the cell when starting to record, I can chose to select Cell, then do the formatting of the cell. Then the macro will look like this: `Selection.SelectCell
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Selection.Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter` Now how do I apply this to my table cell? How do I specify which cell I want to be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding your problem, but if I'm not, it's caused by a simple missing step.  The following works for me (D7), with apologies if it seems a little long-winded, but I started out having the same problem as you:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MSWord,
  Document,
  Table,
  Selection,
  Range,
  Cell : OleVariant;
  Rows,
  Columns,
  ARow,
  AColumn : Integer;
  RowIndex,
  ColIndex : Integer;
  S : String;
begin
  try
    MsWord := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    try
      MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      MsWord.Visible := True;
    except
      Exception.Create('Error');
    end;
  end;
  Rows := 3;
  Columns := 4;
  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;
  Table := MSWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add( Range:= MSWord.Selection.Range, NumRows:= Rows, NumColumns:= Columns, DefaultTableBehavior:= wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= wdAutoFitFixed);

  for ARow := 1 to Rows do begin
    for AColumn := 1 to Columns do begin
      Cell := Table.Cell(ARow, AColumn);
      RowIndex := Cell.RowIndex;
      ColIndex := Cell.ColumnIndex;
      Caption := IntToStr(RowIndex) + '/' + IntToStr(ColIndex);
      Range := Cell.Range;
      Range.Select;
      S := Format('Row: %d, col: %d', [RowIndex, ColIndex]);
      MSWord.Selection.Range := Range;
      MSWord.Selection.TypeText(Text := S);
    end;
  end;

  Cell := Table.Cell(2, 2);
  Range := Cell.Range;
  Range.Select;
  Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphCenter;
end;
```

The key thing is the "range.select"s.  If you comment those out, you'll find that all the text ends up in the 1,1 cell.

Comment: @user1137313: Was this not the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Awesome. It works now. Now I can access the cells like in a grid and set the properties for them super-fast. Thank you

Answer (score -3):

I assume you have already write some complex codes and would prefer not to rewrite you code.  I do however want to advise you to look at TMS Software at [enter link description here](http://www.tmssoftware.com/).  They have very rich table components.

Comment: I actually need to generate a Word document containing text, tables and charts. It's not because I don't know about grids in delphi.

Comment: -1. The question asks specifically about Word automation. If it requested a recommendation for a component set, your answer would apply (although the question would then be off-topic).

Comment: I am talking about using the table component in Delphi and then export your table to word.  One of the advantages is "Save to Word DOC files".  This means you can set up the whole table in Delphi and just export it to World.  I do it all the time.  But hey, I am the loser that cannot program.  Next time value my answers

Comment: It's not that you are wrong to talk about third party components. It's that my question was about working with alignments inside a table Cell. I doubt very much that saving from any Grid component into Word would allow me to affect each cell's alignment. So that is why the guys downvoted your answer. So it's good that I can export a dataset to a word table, but I am past that, and my problem is dealing with the formatting of the destination document. I need to merge cells, align them to center horizontally, vertically, change text colors and so on. I am pretty sure I cannot do that from TMS

Comment: Also the best solution is always a free solution, especially now after most of the automating is done. It would not be very wise of me to stop my work and start all over again from scratch (and spend some money too with the new thing), when the first try was free and almost done.

Comment: TMS components are free if you do not want to modify the source code.  With TMS you can set the alignments and all font properties (font name, size, color etc) for each individual cell.  If you do not find a solution to your issue take a look at the TMS software.